# Java TreeEditor UI bug

Tags: java, tree, swt, progress-bar

Currently I have small bug when using TreeEditor. My code:

```
package test;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.TreeEditor;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ProgressBar;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        Tree tree = new Tree(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        tree.setHeaderVisible(true);
        TreeColumn column1 = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.LEFT);
        column1.setText("Column 1");
        column1.setWidth(200);
        TreeColumn column2 = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.CENTER);
        column2.setText("Column 2");
        column2.setWidth(200);
        TreeColumn column3 = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.RIGHT);
        column3.setText("Column 3");
        column3.setWidth(200);
        TreeColumn column4 = new TreeColumn(tree, SWT.LEFT);
        column4.setText("Column 4");
        column4.setWidth(200);

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            TreeItem item = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);
            item.setText(new String[] { "item " + i, "abc" + i, "percentage " + i });
            ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar(tree, SWT.NULL);
            bar.setVisible(true);
            bar.setSelection(i);
            bar.setToolTipText(i + "%");
            TreeEditor editor = new TreeEditor(tree);
            editor.grabHorizontal = true;
            editor.grabVertical = true;
            editor.setEditor(bar, item, 3);

        }
        // shell.pack();
        shell.setSize(900, 295);
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

When I click the text of bottom row ("item 12"), OS will scroll down 1 row automatically. But when I check ProgressBar ToolTip, "item 12" progress bar shows 11%. It mean that progress bar is not scrolled down one row.
How can I resolve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me that the entire column (when setup using a `ControlEditor`) does not auto-scroll along with the others. Bugs can be reported over here: [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/).

It doesn't seem to be the `ProgressBar` that's the issue. If you replace it with a `Label`, for example, you'll have the same problem.

One possible workaround that seems to work would be to call the `setSelection(TreeItem[])` method in a listener. That seems to get the column to correct itself.

For example:

```
tree.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) {
        tree.setSelection(tree.getSelection());
    }
});
```

Getting the selected `TreeItem`s and then setting them right back should be fairly innocuous as long as your application doesn't do anything special around `SelectionEvent`s on the `Tree`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works. But I think it's like a trick :D

Comment: @DucTran You're welcome! Yea, it's definitely more of a trick since I'm pretty convinced it's an Eclipse bug. If you haven't yet it's definitely worth reporting the bug via the link I provided!